# Magento 2 Amasty Layered Navigation. Remove display of current applied filters

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2, layered-navigation, amasty

I am trying to remove the block which displays all of the current applied filters. Please see image below. Is this done by editing a layout file or via an option in the admin panel? If so how do i it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current filter block can be remove from layout

```
app/code/Amasty/Shopby/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml
```

Or by template file :

```
 app/code/Amasty/Shopby/view/frontend/templates/layer/state.phtml
```

Comment: be careful removing state block in layout file will cause a problem because it is used by its parent block => $this->getChildBlock('state')->getClearUrl();